# How to change the icon for Qt application?

Tags: unity, launcher, application-development, qt

How can I change application icon (launcher icon) for my Qt-application? Now it looks like a question mark and I want to change it.

Comment: Could you please be more specific so others can help you? Do you have the code somewhere we can have a look at? Have you set up a .desktop file? Where is your app's icon currently?

Comment: I don't have .desktop file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon used in the Launcher will be the icon specified in the application's .desktop file.